# What is the string "xxx@xxx:~$" in terminal called?

Tags: linux, terminal

I don't know or I just forget what is `xxx@xxx:~$` called in a terminal terminal?
Is there name for it?

Comment: It's called your prompt or command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the prompt.

If you type `man bash` and then search for the word "prompt", you'll find more information.